# programmatically get ics file from icloud?

Tags: icloud

I've been running a process for a client that involves grabbing their publicly available calendar file from me.com by making an https GET call in a ruby script, and then converting the data in the .ics file to html, then copying it to their website.

They recently upgraded to Lion and iCloud, and it appears that, while the calendar I want is still publicly available, it's only usable by webCal enabled apps--I can no longer get it over https.

I've poked around a bit on google, but haven't see anything that points me in the right direction yet. Does anyone know if there's a way to access public calendars on iCloud via http/https? Or is it strictly via webcCl? The documentation does make it sound like iCloud is designed to only share data among Apple devices. Am I just stuck here?

Answer (score 6):

I'm surprised no one has answered this yet...

If you go to iCloud.com, you should be able to get the URL of the calendar that you have syncing using a public share.  It should be a webcal protocol (webcal://).  However, if you change that webcal to https, it will download the ics format instead of trying to sync using Macs iCalendar.

I have my website linking to the https ics file, and it appears to be working just fine (for now at least).

Comment: This now gives me `{"status": 404, "message": "Could not locate resource"}`. Example URL: webcal://p05-calendarws.icloud.com/ca/subscribe/1/Tn9JZbsKADzA5HbvtQqk-kejlKScBQSPKhC26f1kJzzj1WP2-puAYqXzXTS0d_P3CKMxK_6k7q0GJvuuO2XJ0LDBwi7BA4JslWco6RmHFag

Answer (score 0):

icloud is gona supply an API for developers soon at least thats what they sayed in the last keynote