# Accessing iCloud securely on behalf of user (server to server)

Tags: authentication, icloud, kerberos

Are there step by step instructions anywhere on how to generate a "ticket" for an iCloud user given their username/password.  I'd like to build a service that access iCloud data (server to server) without having to store the iCloud username or password.

My understanding is that you use the username/password to generate a Kerberos ticket from iCloud.  That's based on the answer to [How does Sunrise for iOS use iCloud credentials to access our calendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21505916/how-does-sunrise-for-ios-use-icloud-credentials-to-access-our-calendar/21505999#21505999) .  But I haven't found instructions online on how to do that.

Does anyone know how to do that?  Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at the authentication documentation for icloud? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloutKitWebServicesReference/SettingUpWebServices/SettingUpWebServices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015240-CH24-SW3

Comment: Are you trying to integrate your app with iCloud and have it store/retrieve from the cloud, or do you try to have access to all user data on iCloud?

Answer (score 3):

Let me start by pointing out that by default iCloud app storage is "sandboxed" in containers. A signed application can only access **its own container** without having the API key to authenticate to other application containers. You can make multiple applications share the same container, or use multiple containers in the same application if needed, but essentially you have to be the developer of all applications or have explicit permission to do this. Check out [Incorporating iCloud into your app](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012094-CH1-SW1) and [Enabling CloudKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/EnablingiCloudandConfiguringCloudKit/EnablingiCloudandConfiguringCloudKit.html) for more details.

**Other** (non-appstore) applications and services can authenticate to use an application's data via [CloudKit Web Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloutKitWebServicesReference/SettingUpWebServices/SettingUpWebServices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015240-CH24-SW3):

1. Authenticating to iCloud (redirect based, so credentials still are never revealed and are known only by the user and iCloud server itself);
2. Further authenticating with your application API key;

The process is described in detail [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloutKitWebServicesReference/SettingUpWebServices/SettingUpWebServices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015240-CH24-SW3), as already kindly pointed out by [Adam Taylor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52116/adam-taylor).

All the above being said, If I understand correctly, **you want to have access to all of the user's iCloud data**. I think, you won't be able to do so for multiple reasons:

1. Data is protected by application key, so you need to have this to access a container in addition to the basic credentials;
2. I'm sure that Apple has a design policy to never ask for user credentials in plain text. Asking the user explicitly for credentials will be against their policy and even if it turns out it is not, having the credentials won't help you much, because you have to enter/send them somewhere. But all iCloud authentication mechanisms are designed to ask for authentication only by the end-user.

This is why I don't believe it is possible to just use user credentials and get access to all of their iCloud data. Now, my 2 cents on why Sunrise works:

As far as I understand, the Sunrise application works, because the calendar data is designed to be shared via CalDav, that works on a concrete URL, so you can import and link your calendar in various calendar client applications. The URL can be found out with a bit of investigation. CalDAV is kind of similar to IMAP and POP3 for mailbox access.

Be so kind to elaborate a bit more on what kind of data you're trying to extract (apple application specific, developer application specific, documents, key-value pairs or something else) and me or other users might help you further.